# How can you tell if a specific storyboard is currently active on an element?

Tags: wpf, storyboard

We have a storyboard that we use to indicate a valid value has been typed into a `TextBox`.  Specifically, it sets the background to green, then fades it to light green, then holds there.  If the value doesn't pass, then we remove the storyboard

Here's pseudocode we run when the text changes...

```
if(testPassed)
    PassedAnimationWithHold.Begin(TestTextBox, true);
else // <-- We need a condition here to determine if we actually should remove it or not
    PassedAnimationWithHold.Remove(TestTextBox);
```

The issue is if they start typing invalid characters from the beginning, the code above tries to remove a storyboard that hasn't been applied yet.

Short of adding our own boolean flag, is there a way we can test to see if that storyboard is active on our element?

### Update

@sa_ddam213's answer below seems to be leading in the right direction, but as I called out in the comments, that depends on knowledge of (one of) the ultimate target(s) of the storyboard as well as the property being animated.

For instance, consider our actual storyboard which, when applied to a control, pulses its background light green, then fades back to the pre-animated background color (Note: It is understood we only apply this to objects who have specified a SolidColorBrush for their background, or else this of course would fail as not all brushes have a 'Color' property.)

```
<Storyboard x:Key="{x:Static gr:Storyboards.PassedPulseKey}"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color">

    <ColorAnimation
        From="#F8F8"
        Duration="{StaticResource {x:Static gr:Storyboards.PulseDurationKey}}"
        FillBehavior="Stop" />

</Storyboard>
```

So in order to use his technique, we somehow need to be able to check IsAnimated on the ValueSource of the Color property on the SolidColorBrush stored in the storyboard-applied-to object's Background property.  That's where I hit another wall.

I'm starting to think its better if I use a style with triggers to apply the storyboard instead of via code, then just let the WPF system take care of it.  That would mean I would have to add a 'Passed' property to our ViewModel to bind the trigger to though.  Still, it can be done!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if will work with you code, but in `DependencyPropertyHelper` there is a `GetValueSource` method that will return the current value of a `DependencyProperty` and you can check if it is currently being animated.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets a value that declares whether the property is being animated.
//
// Returns:
//     true if the property is animated; otherwise, false.
public bool IsAnimated { get; }
```

So if your `TextBox` is animating its `BorderBrush` in the Storyboard you could use:

```
if (DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(TestTextBox, TextBox.BorderBrushProperty).IsAnimated)
{
   // stop storyboard
}
```

Comment: This is close, but it requires knowledge of the DependencyProperty being animated, which is internal to the Storyboard.  The Storyboard exposes a GetTargetProperty, but that returns a PropertyPath, which would be relative to the target object, and as such, I don't know of any way to get the property from the target object and a path.  Still, +1 for the info in your post although I can't give this the answer without the missing information.

Comment: BTW, I updated the question with more details, including our actual storyboard.  I'm starting to think its better if I use a style with triggers to apply the storyboard instead of via code, then just let the WPF system take care of it.

Comment: Does not work for me. I'm not using Storyboards per se but the `BeginAnimation()`-method of my adorner. It does animate perfectly fine but your solution does always return true. Any way to actually get if there's an animation running atm?